# Streams composition using withLatesFrom or combineLatest in ngrx effects

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, rxjs5, ngrx-effects

I stumbled upon a weird issue that I can't explain, here is effects code that I'm referring to:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, Effect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest';
import { withLatestFrom, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class SomeEffects {
  constructor (
    private actions$: Actions,
    private smthStore1: Store<fromSmth1.State>,
    private smthStore2: Store<fromSmth2.State>,
    private smthStore3: Store<fromSmth3.State>,
    private smthStore4: Store<fromSmth4.State>,
    private smthStore5: Store<fromSmth5.State>,
  ) {}

  private common$ = combineLatest(
    this.smthStore1.select(fromSmth1.getSmth),
    this.smthStore2.select(fromSmth2.getSmth),
    this.smthStore3.select(fromSmth3.getSmth),
    this.smthStore4.select(fromSmth4.getSmth),
    this.smthStore5.select(fromSmth5.getSmth),
  ).pipe(
    map(([smth1, smth2, smth3, smth4, smth5]) => ({ smth1, smth2, smth3, smth4, smth5 }))
  );

  @Effect({ dispatch: false })
  public someEffect$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType(actions.SOME_ACTION),
      withLatestFrom(this.common$),
      tap(([action, data]) => do something...),
    );
}
```

So I have several effects relying on common$ stream. This is a stream that I built purely to not repeat myself in every effect and just compose actions$ and common$ for the same effect, but for some reason this does not work. App just stops loading without any errors.

Now if I comment out withLatestFrom, app is working again:

```js
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
public someEffect$ = this.actions$
  .pipe(
    ofType(actions.SOME_ACTION),
//    withLatestFrom(this.common$),
    tap(([action, data]) => do something...),
  );
```

Is there something I'm missing about rxjs and ngrx?

Angular 5
RxJS 5

Comment: withLatestFrom blocks emissions till at least one value has been emitted (AFTER the subscription). and combineLatest only emits once every stream inside it has emitted at least once. so it sounds like an inner stream isn't emitting.

Comment: Can you make a demo that replicates the problem? Your code looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

there could be many reasons, since you just need some values from store try this

```
  private common$ = withLatestFrom(
    this.smthStore1.select(fromSmth1.getSmth),
    this.smthStore2.select(fromSmth2.getSmth),
    this.smthStore3.select(fromSmth3.getSmth),
    this.smthStore4.select(fromSmth4.getSmth),
    this.smthStore5.select(fromSmth5.getSmth)
  ).pipe(
    map(([smth1, smth2, smth3, smth4, smth5]) => ({ smth1, smth2, smth3, smth4, smth5 }))
  );

@Effect({ dispatch: false })
  public someEffect$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType(actions.SOME_ACTION),
      concatMap(action => of(action).pipe(this.common$))
      tap(([action, {smth1, smth2, smth3, smth4, smth5}]) => do something...),
    );
```

also if you want to keep using `combineLatest` you need to change the syntax to

```
private common$ = combineLatest([
    this.smthStore1.select(fromSmth1.getSmth),
    this.smthStore2.select(fromSmth2.getSmth),
    this.smthStore3.select(fromSmth3.getSmth),
    this.smthStore4.select(fromSmth4.getSmth),
    this.smthStore5.select(fromSmth5.getSmth),
  ]).pipe(
    map(([smth1, smth2, smth3, smth4, smth5]) => ({ smth1, smth2, smth3, smth4, smth5 }))
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
private common$ = combineLatest([
    this.smthStore1.select(fromSmth1.getSmth),
    this.smthStore2.select(fromSmth2.getSmth),
    this.smthStore3.select(fromSmth3.getSmth),
    this.smthStore4.select(fromSmth4.getSmth),
    this.smthStore5.select(fromSmth5.getSmth),
  ]).pipe(
    map(([smth1, smth2, smth3, smth4, smth5]) => ({ smth1, smth2, smth3, smth4, smth5 })),
    shareReplay(1),
  );
```